# wifi connection and USB data modem together

Tags: wireless, usb, modem

I want to connect my laptop to a camera's wifi... and transfer pics to the laptop... (no problem so far...)

2. Then I want to use the laptop, via a USB CELL data modem, to capture a selected pic, and www email or SMS it to a typed address...

Having trouble getting both Wifi and and USB Data cell connection to play nicely together... One or the other wants to be ON and turn/force the other OFF, even though only one (USB data modem) is accessing the internet.

Thoughts?

markg

Comment: Do you really need them both connected at once? Just transfer the photos, switch connections and send them.